# Inverse of concatenation?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The concatenation of two elements is described as follows:

$$a = a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n$$

$$b = b_1 b_2 \cdots b_m$$

$$ a \bullet b = a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n b_1 b_2 \cdots b_m $$

Clearly $\lambda$ acts as an operative identity as can be shown given  $\lambda$ is the empty set:

$$ a \bullet \lambda = \lambda \bullet a = a$$

Are there any values such that

$$ a \bullet a^{-1} = \lambda $$

That is, what does the inverse of a concatenation look like? Is there one? Does an identity element need to satisfy the above equation to be an identity element?

Comment: The length of $a \bullet b$ equals the sum of the individual lengths, so there cannot be an inverse element ( you would need an element of negative length).

Comment: What are these elements of?  If you form the free monoid on a set of symbols then every element except for the empty string is not invertible.

Comment: @you what is a free monoid my friend?

Comment: If you allow "anti"-elements, then it works fine.  We say a word is in simplest form if there exist no letter next to its anti-letter.  We may cancel out adjacent pairs of letters and anti-letters.  Two words are said to be equal if their simplest forms are the same.  For example, with alphabet $\{a,a^{-1},b,b^{-1}\}$ you would have things like $aba^{-1}bb$ concatenated with $b^{-1}b^{-1}aaba^{-1}$ would be $aba^{-1}bbb^{-1}b^{-1}aaba^{-1} = ababa^{-1}$.  See [Free group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group).

Comment: You would have then the inverse of a word $a_1a_2a_3\dots a_k$ would be the word $a_k^{-1}a_{k-1}^{-1}\dots a_2^{-1}a_1^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean when you write $a^{-1}$?

Your setup makes sense. As long as you do only multiply you can concatenate products $a_ia_i\ldots a_i$ of $k$ equal factors to $a_i^k$ and obtain the *free semigroup* on $n$ generators $a_1$, $\ldots$, $a_n$.

But you can only talk about things like $a^{-1}$ if you admit right at the start together with any generator $a_i$ its inverse $a_i^{-1}$. In this way you obtain the *free group* on $n$ generators $a_1$, $\ldots$, $a_n$. The inverse of the element $a_3a_7a_2$ is then given by $a_2^{-1}a_7^{-1}a_3^{-1}$, etcetera. The details of this, together with all necessary induction proofs, are presented in any textbook on group theory.